View Not Updating When @Binding Changes
I'm trying to update an item UI when it's selected, but it's not working as I would expect (I'm new to SwiftUI).
I have the main view as follows:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var item: MyItem = .first

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Select your position:")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.bottom)
            ItemGridView(selectedItem: $item)
        }
        .padding()
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}

ItemGridView is as follows:
struct ItemGridView: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
            ForEach(MyItem.allCases) { item in
                ItemView(name: item.name,
                         isSelected: item == self.selectedItem)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedItem = item
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The ItemView is as follows:
struct ItemView: View {
    let name: String

    @State var isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
                .padding(3)
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.brown.opacity(0.8))
        }
        .padding(3)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .background(.brown)
        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 25))
        .shadow(color: isSelected ? .black : .clear, radius: 10)
        .overlay {
            if isSelected {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                    .opacity(0.5)
            }
        }
    }
}

The Data object is:
enum MyItem: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case first
    case second
    case third
    
    var id: Currency { self }
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            "First"
        case .second:
            "Second"
        case .third:
            "Third"
        }
    }
}

It does not work even if instead of the Binding I have a State variable, like @State private var selectedItem = Item() inside ItemGridView.
Is there any way to tell the view to redraw when selectedItem changes?

Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce your issue.

Updated with all the views I have.

Does this answer your question? Why isn't this simple SwiftUI view updated?

Thanks. That question shows why my code is not working: MyItem identity is not changed, so it's not updated. Still I've no ideia how I should go about to make this work…

Change @State var isSelected: Bool to a let, State should always be private

why do you use LazyVGrid? I copy and paste your code, and noted that onTapGesture not called . I add onTapGesture on LazyVGrid and view was updated.
